# Could not retrieve information from environment from production source on files

Tags: puppet

I've setup a puppet module to install and keep the bacula backup system running on a number of systems. I'm using puppet 3.7.5 with SELinix on both the puppet server and the clients.

Part of the formula I've come up with is to transfer an SSL cert/key pair to each host that uses the module. So that bacula can work over TLS.

I have this defined in my bacula config manifest:

```
 file { "/etc/pki/tls/private/${::hostname}.mydomain.com.key":
       notify  => Service["bacula-fd"],
       owner => "bacula",
       group => "bacula",
       mode => 0400,
       require => Package["bacula-client","bacula-common"],
       source => "puppet:///modules/bacula/${::hostname}/${::hostname}.mydomain.com.key",
      }

     file { "/etc/pki/tls/certs/${::hostname}.mydomain.com.crt":
        notify  => Service["bacula-fd"],
        owner => "bacula",
        group => "bacula",
        mode => 0400,
        require => Package["bacula-client","bacula-common"],
       source => "puppet:///modules/bacula/${::hostname}/${::hostname}.mydomain.com.crt",
     }
```

This has been working perfectly fine for a while now. But only on SOME hosts that were recently added I'm getting "Could not retrieve information" errors on the keypairs that I'm trying to send over.

```
 Error: /Stage[main]/Bacula::Config/File[/etc/pki/tls/certs/monitor1.mydomain.com.crt]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s)      puppet:///modules/bacula/monitor1/monitor1.mydomain.com.crt     
 Error: /Stage[main]/Bacula::Config/File[/etc/pki/tls/private/monitor1.mydomain.com.key]: Could not evaluate:      Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s)      puppet:///modules/bacula/monitor1/monitor1.mydomain.com.key
```

And this is the weird part! All of the directories that I'm transferring keys and certs from have identical ownership and permissions for both the working and the non working hosts!

This is a directory listing of certs and keys that does NOT work:

```
 /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/bacula/files/monitor1:
 total 8.0K
 -rw-r--r--. 1 puppet puppet 2.0K Jun 16 21:53 monitor1.mydomain.com.crt
 -rw-r--r--. 1 puppet puppet 3.2K Jun 16 21:53 monitor1.mydomain.com.key
```

And this is a listing from a directory containing certs and keys that DOES work:

```
/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/bacula/files/logs:
 total 8.0K
 -rw-r--r--. 1 puppet puppet 1.9K Apr 23 22:14 logs.mydomain.com.crt
 -rw-r--r--. 1 puppet puppet 3.2K Apr 23 22:14 logs.mydomain.com.key
```

And these are permissions on the directories themselves:

```
 drwxr-xr-x. 2 puppet puppet 62 Jun 16 22:13 /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/bacula/files/logs
 drwxr-xr-x. 2 puppet puppet 70 Jun 16 22:14 /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/bacula/files/monitor1
```

Trouble is I can tell no difference between the working and non working directories.

If I run puppet  with the bacula module on the monitor1 host, I get the error. If I run puppet with the bacula module on the logs host, everything works fine!  Same formula in the config manifest, different directories but same permissions on both, yet only one fails! This just isn't making any sense to me.

Puppet should be able to select the correct directory name to pull from for the monitor1 host based on the $hostname fact just as it does for the logs host.

I'm just wondering what I may be missing that could get rid of that error!

Comment: You could activate debug logging on the master. Do you use SElinux? POSIX ACLs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do use SELinux on both the puppet master and the clients. How would I activate debug logging on the master? I'm on puppet 3.7.5 on the master and clients.

Comment: I just found that disabling SELinux on the puppet server gets rid of the error I'm getting on the client. But I don't want to leave it disabled forever. How do I fix this?

This is what I found in my audit logs:

    type=AVC msg=audit(1434769414.956:562): avc:  denied  { open } for      pid=3558 comm="ruby"     path="/etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/bacula/files/monitor   1/monitor1.mydomain.com.crt" dev="vda1" ino=1842005    scontext=system_u:system_r:passenger_t:s0   tcontext=system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0 tclass=file

Comment: Well, that's literally the most common occurence when employing SELinux. Read up on contexts and alter either your service runtime or file contexts. If your studies don't get you there, you might want to ask for help on ServerFault.